# Are there other natural reactors than the Oklo mine? Any still active?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

Actually my question is more whether any other natural reactor has been *found*, despite the one at [Oklo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklo). And whether there are any known active natural reactors these days.

Bonus question: if there are (or were) from what distance is it (or would it be) safe?

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of any other natural fission reactors.

### Could it be active?

No it can't, because nowadays the abundance of U-235 is too low for a nuclear chain reaction using natural uranium and natural water as a moderator.

U-235 has a shorter half-life (700 million years) than U-238 (4.5 milliard/billion years), therefore the abundance of U-235 in natural uranium of the solar system is decreasing.